# App icon not showing in in-app Game Center VC (GKGameCenterViewController)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, appicon

I've implemented a Game on iOS that integrates with Game Center. I have a button that opens the in-app Game Center VC (`GKGameCenterViewController`). In that VC, there seems to be some empty space before the app name. I believe an app icon is supposed to be displayed there, but it's not working.

I have filled-out all the app icon asset sizes, and have uploaded the app to App Store Connect.
The icon shows in App Store Connect.

I was wondering if the app needs to be fully released on the App Store for the icon to magically appear?

Other games on my phone show the icon there, I wonder why mine doesn't?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems to be tied to setting a leaderboard on App Store Connect. Once I did that, a few seconds later, opening `GKGameCenterViewController`, on my phone, showed the icon as desired.

To add the leaderboard go to your App's App Store Connect page:

1. Scroll down to Game Center, and under leaderboards, click the Select Leaderboards button.

   [Select Leaderboards on App Store Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TL7F.png)
2. Select the checkbox next to your leaderboard, and click the Done button.

   [Add Leaderboards on App Store Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOSUH.png)

After a few seconds, you can open up `GKGameCenterViewController` on your phone, and the icon should start to load in.